# R Match data tables using string matching

Tags: r, data.table, string-matching

I have two data tables:

```
dt1 <- data.table(V1=c("Apple Pear Orange, AAA111", "Grapes Banana Pear .BBB222", "Orange Kiwi Melon ,CCC333.", "Apple DDD444, Pear Orange", "Kiwi Melon Orange, CCC333", "Apple Pear Orange, AAA111", "Tomato Cucumber-EEE222", "Seagull Pigeon ZZZ111" ), stringsAsFactors = F)

dt2 <- data.table(Code=c("AAA111", "AAA222", "AAA333", "AAA444", "AAA555", "AAA666", "BBB111", "BBB222", "BBB333", "BBB444", "BBB555", "BBB666", "CCC111", "CCC222", "CCC333", "CCC444", "CCC555", "CCC666", "DDD111", "DDD222", "DDD333", "DDD444", "DDD555", "DDD666", "EEE111", "EEE222", "EEE333", "EEE444", "EEE555", "EEE666"), stringsAsFactors = F)
dt2$Ref <- 1:nrow(dt2)
```

Each row in `dt1` contains an unformatted string that includes a 'Code'. `dt2` contains a list of codes that can be matched. What I am after is a way for the 'Code' part of the string in each row of `dt1` to be identified and then matched with the corresponding code in `dt2`. If there is no matching code in `dt2` then NA is returned.

Here is the type of output I am after:

```
dt3 <- data.table(V1=c("Apple Pear Orange, AAA111", "Grapes Banana Pear .BBB222", "Orange Kiwi Melon ,CCC333.", "Apple DDD444, Pear Orange", "Kiwi Melon Orange, CCC333", "Apple Pear Orange, AAA111", "Tomato Cucumber-EEE222", "Seagull Pigeon ZZZ111"), Code=c("AAA111", "BBB222", "CCC333", "DDD444", "CCC333", "AAA111", "EEE222", "NA"), Ref=c("1", "8", "15", "22", "15", "1", "26", "NA"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I have tried using regex, grep etc. to find a solution but have not got anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regex_left_join` from my [fuzzyjoin](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin) package:

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)
regex_left_join(dt1, dt2, by = c(V1 = "Code"))
#>                            V1   Code Ref
#> 1:  Apple Pear Orange, AAA111 AAA111   1
#> 2: Grapes Banana Pear .BBB222 BBB222   8
#> 3: Orange Kiwi Melon ,CCC333. CCC333  15
#> 4:  Apple DDD444, Pear Orange DDD444  22
#> 5:  Kiwi Melon Orange, CCC333 CCC333  15
#> 6:  Apple Pear Orange, AAA111 AAA111   1
#> 7:     Tomato Cucumber-EEE222 EEE222  26
#> 8:      Seagull Pigeon ZZZ111     NA  NA
```

Comment: Thanks. Does exactly what I am after.